# How select a check box on loading a page using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have number of check boxes in my single page

```
<div class="check-outer">
    <label>Place of operation</label>
    <div class="checkDiv">
        <div ng-repeat="place in places">
            <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="placesOBJ[place.place_id]">
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <label class="chk-lbl">{{place.place_name}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working perfectly. If data is present then i want to defaultly check this check boxes

```
if($scope.client.client_places){
    var plcLength = $scope.client.client_places.length;
    var client_places = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < plcLength; i++){
        client_places[i] = $scope.client.client_places[i]['place_id'];
    }
    // console.log(client_places);
    //$scope.placesOBJ4 = client_places;
    $scope.placesOBJ = client_places;
}
```

client places contain an array like {1, 2}

But this is not working. if any one know about this please help me.

Comment: $scope.placesOBJ4 should be $scope.placesOBJ ... is this just a typo? correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: ng-checked="true".. will solve your issue..

Comment: You want checked checkbox those are in 'placesObj' array right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive ng-checked and pass in an expression based on the model

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-checked`to achieve what you need

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="placesOBJ[place.place_id]" ng-checked="placesOBJ">
```

If `$scope.placesOBJ` is populated (not null) then the expression is true and the checkbox will be selected

Comment: if any structure i need to follow?. My array placesOBJ contain {1, 2}. This checked all my check boxes

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this simple code It will be useful for you

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl" ng-init="init()">

    <div>
          <label>Place of operation</label>

                    <div ng-repeat="place in places" ng-show="check">
                          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="placesOBJ[place.id]" ng-checked="true">
                          <label class="chk-lbl">{{place.name}}</label>
                    </div>

    </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope) {

        $scope.check=false;
        $scope.places=[{'id':1, 'name':'place1'},{'id':2, 'name':'place2'},{'id':3, 'name':'place3'},{'id':4, 'name':'place4'}];

        $scope.init=function()
        {
            if($scope.places)
            {
                $scope.check=true;
            }
        }

    }]);

  </script>
</body>
```

Explanation:- You can make use of `ng-init="init()"` to call on page load , it will check if data is present or not. If present then set `ng-show="true"` else by default it will be `false`

Comment: assuming your client_places is having the same structure as $scope.places in my code.